# Start & Stop lottie player/animation with buttons

Tags: javascript, html, animation, lottie

Very basic stuff, but im still struggling with javascript.

I have this lottie animation, which is not svg.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_6gduajmo.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" controls></lottie-player>

<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

My goal is to have a button(#start) to start the animation and play it one time, then remain in the last frame.
Second button(#stop) should either jump immediately to the first frame of the animation or simply revert it and remain in the first frame.

It's basically the same functionality as the standard lottie controls. But I need the button to control something else as well, and I don't want the timeline of lottie controls.

I tried to fiddle with this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sangziii/pen/OogKYZ?editors=1010), and insert my file, but I didn't manage to work it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use methods `play()` and `stop()` on **lottie** by declaring each method inside the event of the corresponding button.

To hide the standard navigation bar remove attribute `controls` in tag `lottie-player`.

You can read in detail [here](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-player).

```js
let player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");
let play = document.querySelector("#start");
let stop = document.querySelector("#stop");

play.onclick = function () {
    player.play();
};

stop.onclick = function () {
    player.stop();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
<lottie-player src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_6gduajmo.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></lottie-player>

<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this example I leave it up to JQuery to start/stop the lottie animation:

```js
$('#start').click(function(){
    $('lottie-player').get(0).play();
});
$('#stop').click(function(){
    $('lottie-player').get(0).stop();
});
```

You need to use `.get(0)` to run play/stop on an HTML object, not the JQuery object.